# Check effective permission for user on database object

Tags: t-sql, permissions

I'm convinced that another question like this must already have been asked somewhere on the internet but I just can't find it.

I'm trying to check the effective permission of a user on an object.  I can easily look up the permission if I've explicitly granted permission:

```
SELECT TOP(100) * FROM sys.database_permissions p
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals dp ON ( p.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id )
WHERE major_id = object_id( 'sp_OACreate' )
```

But I'm looking for the effective permissions for users with roles like SysAdmin etc for which there won't exist a record.

The end result I'm trying to achieve is to be able to query the effective permission of a user and to then grant permission if they're lacking the permission

Comment: isn't this should have @objest_id or else

Comment: @Rush.2707 In this case the `object_id( 'sp_OACreate' )` should be sufficient unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

Managed to find this page detailing [HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189802(v=sql.110).aspx) which seems to have done the trick

```
DECLARE @User nvarchar(30) = 'MyUser'
DECLARE @Script nvarchar(max)

IF ( CURRENT_USER != 'dbo' )
BEGIN
    Print 'Please execute as ''dbo'' user'
    RETURN
END 

IF ( HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME( @User, 'LOGIN', 'IMPERSONATE' ) = 0 )
BEGIN
    Print 'Can''t Impersonate ' + @User
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    DECLARE @HasPermission bit

    EXECUTE AS LOGIN = @User
    SELECT @HasPermission = HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME( 'sp_OACreate', 'OBJECT', 'EXECUTE' )
    REVERT

    IF ( @HasPermission = 'false' )
    BEGIN
        SET @Script = 'USE master; GRANT EXECUTE ON [sys].[sp_OACreate] TO [' + @User + ']'
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @Script
    END
END
```

Hopefully this will help someone else.